# Parameter not supported by web service

Tags: web-services, rest, language-agnostic

I want to validate an opinion with you.

I have to design a web service that searches into a database of restaurants affiliated to a discount program in a specific country around a given address.
The REST call to such a webservice will look like `http://server/search?country=<countryCode>&language=<languageCode>&address=<address>&zipcode=<zipcode>`

The problem is that some countries do not have zipcodes or do not have them in the entire country.

Now, what would you do if the user passes such a parameter for a country that does not have zipcodes, but he/she passes a valid address?

1. Return 400 Bad request.
2. Simply igonre the zipcode parameter and return results based on the valid address
3. Return an error message in a specific format (e.g. JSON) stating that zipcodes are not supported for that country

Some colleagues are also favoring the following option
 4. Simply return no results. And state in the documentation that the zipcode parameter is not supported. Also we have to create a webservice method which returns what fields should be displayed in the user interface.

What option do you think is best and why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well the OpenStreetMap Nomination Server returns results even if you dont know the ZIP Code and you can look at the results anyway. What if the user doesnt know the zip code but wants to find hist object?
I would try to search for that specific object anyway, especially because you said that some countries have zip codes partially.

If you simply return nothing te user doesnt know what went wrong and he wont know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

That would depend on the use case. How easy is it for a user of the API to trigger that case? Is it a severe error which the user really should know how to avoid? Or is it something that is not entirely clear, where a user may know (or think he knows) a zipcode where officially there shouldn't be one? Does it come down to trial and error for the user how to retrieve correct results from your API? Is it a bad enough error that the user needs to be informed about it and that he needs to handle this on his side?

If you place this restriction in your API, consider that it will have to be clearly documented when this case is triggered, every user of the API will have to read and understand that documentation, it needs to be clear how to avoid the problem, it needs to be possible for the user to avoid the problem and every user will have to correctly implement extra code on his side to avoid this problem. Is it possible for the user to easily know which areas have zipcodes and which don't?

I think the mantra of "be flexible in what you accept, strict in what you output" applies...